# Storing image_id after uploading image in article table

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543892/using-php-to-upload-an-image-and-store-data-in-mssql) I succeeded to create upload image, but now I need to store the `image_id` into another table called `articles`. I do not know if this is correct, but I tried to select the image_id from table image like this

```
$select_image=mysql_query("select image_id from image where image_name = $fileName") or die(mysql_error());
```

and fetch the result to my article insert query like this

```
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($select_image);

$query=mysql_query("insert into articles (article_name,article_category,article_subcategory,article_body,article_summary,article_tags,article_photo,article_timedate) values ('$article_title','$CategoryID','$ProductID','$article_body','$article_summary','$fetch[image_id]','$time')") or die ('Error, Query Faild'.mysql_error());
```

Is this correct ? The mysql_error keeps saying

> Unknown column 'Penguins.jpg' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select the last inserted id by calling

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

instead of

```
select image_id from image where image_name = $fileName
```

Comment: how should i fetch this one in another select query ?

Comment: just replace select image_id ... with SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() 
there is no need to select the actual row just to get the primary key (id) i assume you DO use auto_increment for your id fields :) only if you do this will work

Comment: @Bader you don't need any query as PHP has already a function for you. Better to read a PHP manual than not so smart SO answers

Answer (score 3):

This is mysql syntax related question.
All data goes directly into the query must be prepared using 2 rules:
1. data must be escaped using mysql_real_escape_string() function
2. enclosed in quotes

So, the code must be

```
$fileName=mysql_real_escape_string($fileName);
$select_image=mysql_query("select image_id from image where image_name = '$fileName'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, if you inserted your image right before this query, no need to select it's id. you can use `mysql_insert_id()` function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your filename is not quoted, so your MySQL server is trying to process the query:

```
select image_id from image where image_name = Penguins.jpg
```

What's worse is that someone uploaded a file called

> 1; EVIL MYSQL QUERY HERE

they would be able to execute arbitrary MySQL on your server. This is known as an SQL injection attack.

Check out the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) that covers this.

Comment: I'd say this is not the scaring injection issue, but just wrong syntax issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$fileName` in quotes in your first query, i.e. `'$fileName'`