# PHP to store data into MSSQL DB

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, insert

I'm new to PHP and SQL, so this is something of a big bite for me...

I've got the following PHP code to connect to a server and select a specific Database inside the DBMS:

```
$server = 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'asda');
mssql_select_db('Feedback', $link);
```

I have some values stored in variables like so:

```
$VariableA = $_POST['Field1'];
$VariableB = $_POST['Field2'];
```

How do I go about storing these variables into a table named 'Data', with the columns 'Name' and 'Rating'?

Comment: Please make use of the search.

Comment: I did, and I didn't find anything that seemed to fit the answer...

Comment: You are looking for the MSSQL INSERT SQL statement. Search for that. If no such documentation exists, I would immediately drop the product. - And here on SO, related is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543892/using-php-to-upload-an-image-and-store-data-in-mssql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498692/insert-php-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many php frameworks that are available for you to develop your system. I have used cakephp which helps you to do database quires easily. Why not you look at such frameworks?

The syntax should be something like this:

```
<?php $in_sql= "INSERT INTO DATA Values(" .$VariableA.",".$VariableB ")"; ?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Well... Sorry for the super late reply, but yes, that's more or less what I needed... I'll get into frameworks when I fully understand the base code, that way I'll know what the framework is doing when its condensing functions and what not...